# factor graph with normal distribution

Tags: distribution, gaussian, message-passing

I'm reading about factor graph and try to understand it. I'm looking for a real example (possibly with hand calculation or python or r code) of how a factor graph works with given normal distribution in each variable node.

Apologize if my question sounds trivial to some of you, but it will help my understanding of these topics. Thank you very much

best,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find some examples on **GitHub**, and im also looking for what I can understand, like [py-factorgraph](https://github.com/mbforbes/py-factorgraph)

Of course, you can read paper like this following:
**Modeling Emotion Influence in ImageSocial Networks**

im trying to understand and rewrite the code of this paper, but this is really difficult....